# configure: error: *** Unable to locate Tk includes

Tags: configuration, compiling

I am trying to install the latest stable release of GRASS GIS from SVN. In the stage of running configure command I get the following error at the last stage.

```
checking for location of Tcl/Tk includes... /usr/include/tcl8.5
checking for tcl.h... yes
checking for tk.h... no
configure: error: *** Unable to locate Tk includes.
```

The command I run for configuration is -

```
./configure --with-tcltk-includes=/usr/include/tcl8.5 --with-proj-share=/usr/share/proj
```

Can anyone suggest me what I am missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would appear to be `tk8.5-dev` you can install it by doing `sudo apt-get install tk8.5-dev`

To find out missing files in the future you can use apt-file (`sudo apt-get install apt-file`). After installing do `apt-file update` and then you can search for your missing file. For example in this case I did `apt-file search tk.h` and it brought up `tk8.5-dev`.

Another neat trick is if the package already exists in the repositories (it does as `grass`) you can do `sudo apt-get build-dep PACKAGE` (in this case `sudo apt-get build-dep grass`) which will install all the dependancies for GRASS allowing you to compile it with ease.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have saved me hours of time. I could use apt-file search option to solve next few similar errors which came up.

Comment: "don't give a man a fish teach him how to fish": +1 for `apt-file`, will be very useful